# Are there problems with this corollary of Schur's Lemma?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

My textbook gives Schur's Lemma as follows:

> Let $T_1: G \to GL(V_1)$ and $T_2: G \to GL(V_2)$ be two irreducible representations of some group $G$, and $A: V_1 \to V_2$ an intertwining operator between the two operators. Then either $A = 0$ and $A: V_1 \to V_2$ is an isomorphism between $V_1$ and $V_2$ (this latter case means, by definition, that the two representations are equivalent).

It then gives the following corollary, where I have bolded things I am unsure about/have added because I think they have been incorrectly omitted (and ask questions thereafter):

> Let $T : G \to GL(V)$ be an **irreducible** representation of a **finite** group $G$ on a **finite-dimensional** complex vector space $V$ and $A : V \to V$ an operator that commutes with all $T (g)$; $AT(g) = T(g)A$ for all $g \in G$. Then $A = \alpha \textrm{id} \,V$ for some complex scalar $\alpha$.

I believe there are two problems with the corollary as stated, but wanted to check:

A) Surely we must state that $T$ is irreducible in the corollary's hypothesis (since Schur's Lemma is used in the proof)?

B) Why is the hypothesis that $G$ is finite presented? As far as I can tell, that hypothesis was not used in the proof. I wonder if instead one is meant to use that $V$ is finite-dimensional, since one uses that $A$ has an eigenvalue and this is only true if $V$ is finite-dimensional?

I then also have the following corollary, where again I have bolded things I am unsure of/have added because I think they have been incorrectly omitted :

> If $G$ is a **finite** abelian group then all its irreducible representations **on complex finite-dimensional vector spaces** are one-dimensional.

C) This depends on the answer to the above, but I believe that since I am using the first corollary to Schur's Lemma I need the bolded hypotheses. Again, I am not sure why $G$ being finite is relevant.

Comment: This definitely needs more focus!

Comment: I'm confused: you state a corollary that starts "Let $T$ be an irreducible representation..." and then you ask "Shouldn't the corollary assume that $T$ is irreducible?"

Comment: @Joppy I have added that part to the statement of the theorem; it is not present in the textbook I am reading. I am essentially wondering whether each bolded part is necessary.

Comment: @Shaun Would it be cleaner if I deleted the proofs? I just put them there because I didn't want people to think I hadn't thought about it. At any rate, my question is essentially *are each of the bolded parts in the theorem statements necessary*?

Comment: @Shaun The main part of my question is about understanding when it's necessary to have that $G$ finite versus when it's necessary that the representation of $G$ be finite (i.e. $V$ finite-dimensional).

Comment: 1. You definitely need the hypothesis that $V$ is irreducible. 2. An irreducible representation of a finite group is necessarily finite-dimensional (the orbit $G \cdot v$ of any nonzero vector has dimension at most $|G|$, and is a $G$-stable subspace, so must be the whole of $V$ by irreducibility). So you need only require that $G$ is finite. 3. If $G$ is infinite but $V$ is finite-dimensional, then the usual argument goes through just fine (find an eigenvalue, etc etc). 4. If $G$ is infinite and $V$ is infinite, then Schur's lemma might hold but is difficult without more structure.

Comment: @Joppy Gosh, my book has royally screwed up then. If I am understanding you correctly, I should then amend the first corollary to "Let $T : G \to GL(V)$ be an **irreducible** representation of a group $G$ on a **finite-dimensional** complex vector space $V$ and $A : V \to V$ an operator that commutes with all $T (g)$; $AT(g) = T(g)A$ for all $g \in G$. Then $A = \alpha \textrm{id} \,V$ for some complex scalar $\alpha$." (removing that the group need be finite) and...

Comment: ...with respect to the second, I should modify to "If $G$ is an abelian group then all its irreducible representations **on complex finite-dimensional vector spaces** are one-dimensional." (removing that $G$ need be finite, but emphasizing that the vector space does need to be complex)?

Comment: That's right - the first Schur's lemma you cited is very general, but the second and third are really specialised to finite-dimensional vector spaces over an algebraically closed field. For instance, a finite cyclic group has a two-dimensional representation acting by rotations on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is irreducible.

Comment: I see, thank you @Joppy. If you'd like to post an answer including the above I'd be delighted to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is a general version of Schur's lemma that only relies on irreducibility, and not on any finiteness conditions or anything about the base field.

> *(Schur's lemma, general)* Let $G$ be a group, and $f: V \to W$ a $G$-equivariant map between representations. Then:
>
> 1. If $V$ is irreducible, then $f$ is either zero or injective,
> 2. If $W$ is irreducible, then $f$ is either zero or surjective,
> 3. If both $V$ and $W$ are irreducible, then $f$ is either zero or an isomorphism.

The proof is almost by definition of an irreducible representation. For example, by $G$-equivariance of $f$, the subspace $\ker f \subseteq V$ is a $G$-stable subspace, and then in (1) by irreducibility of $V$, we must either have $\ker f = V$ (hence $f$ is zero) or $\ker f = 0$ (hence $f$ is injective). The proofs of (2) and (3) are similar.

The next version of Schur's lemma holds for finite-dimensional irreducible representations over an algebraically closed field. $G$ can be infinite, but also note that if $G$ is finite, then any irreducible representation is automatically finite-dimensional.

> *(Schur's lemma, algebraically closed field)* Let $G$ be a group, $V$ an irreducible representation of $G$ over the algebraically closed field $k$, and $f: V \to V$ a $G$-equivariant endomorphism. Then $f$ is a scalar map, i.e. $f = \lambda \operatorname{id}_V$ for some $\lambda \in k$.

The proof goes: since $k$ is algebraically closed and $V$ is finite-dimensional, $f$ has some eigenvalue $\lambda \in k$. The linear map $f - \lambda \operatorname{id}_V$ is then a $G$-equivariant map between irreducible representations, but it is not invertible, so it is zero by the general version of Schur's lemma. Hence $f = \lambda \operatorname{id}_V$.

The last result about abelian groups follows from the algebraically closed version of Schur's lemma. Again it needs no finiteness conditions on $G$.

> Let $G$ be an abelian group, and $V$ a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of $G$ over an algebraically closed field. Then $V$ is one-dimensional.

The proof goes like this. For any $g \in G$ we can define the left-multiplication map $L_g: V \to V$ by $L_g(v) = gv$. Since $G$ is abelian, $L_g$ is a $G$-equivariant map: for any $h \in G$ we have $L_g(hv) = ghv = hgv = h L_g(v)$. Applying the algebraically closed version of Schur's lemma, we see that $L_g$ is a scalar, and therefore every element of $G$ just scales vectors. So for any nonzero $v \in V$, the subspace spanned by $v$ is a subrepresentation, and by irreducibility must be the whole space.